# accessing videos uploaded to a page via the Graph API

Tags: facebook-graph-api

I need to fetch videos uploaded by users to a Facebook Page.

I'd have expected them to show up in https://graph.facebook.com/me/videos/uploaded, but it appears this only covers videos I've uploaded to my profile, not to a page.

The only place I can find that these show up is https://graph.facebook.com/PageName/tagged, but there they're crammed in amongst all the other stuff and I can't filter to find just the authenticated user's uploads to the page.

Is there a way to get only a specific user's video uploads / tags to a page?

Comment: By “uploaded to a page”, do you mean really uploaded or just posted to the page’s wall?

Comment: Posted to the page's wall, with no special permissions on that page. i.e. I upload a video of myself to the McDonalds page because I just love McDonalds that much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, if we’re just talking videos posted to the wall here, I guess you could get that info querying the [FQL `stream` table](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/stream/).

Filter it by:

- source_id: The ID of the page whose wall the post is on
- actor_id: The ID of the user that published the post
- type: "128" - Video posted

Information about the video should be in the `attachment` column.